# Drawing 256 squares/rectangles in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, printing, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to draw 256 small sized squares using MATLAB rectangle function. If I am drawing abut 10 squares then the following works fine:

```
for i=1:2:40

rectangle('Position',[5,3+i,0.3,0.3],...
      'Curvature',[0,0],...
     'LineStyle','-', 'faceColor', 'black')

end

axis off; 

daspect([1,1,1])
```

[image]

But when I change the last value of for loop to 512 (to draw 256 squares), it is not printing properly:

[image]

Here is the magnified version of a section of the above image:
[image]

This image clearly shows some thing is wrong somewhere as the sides of the squares are not perfectly equal and that the **squares are becoming smaller in size for higher no. of squares**: Can anybody help me draw the squares perfectly **with size not diminishing**,  ? (I don't have any issues with memory, and I can tolerate multiple pages scrolling down for covering entire squares )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine even when the loop does 512 iterations - when you zoom-in in the final matlab figure. The artifacts you describe are probably caused by the monitor resolution or a low resolution while exporting to non-vector files.

Try to export your image as a vector file (eps or svg) to see that everything looks fine when you zoom in.

Answer (score 5):

It is a classical [Moire effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern). You can't show that much rectangles on your monitor, because there aren't enough pixels. Matlab does some down-sampling for you. Thus, you get another frequency, that did not exist originally.

Comment: But it can very well wrap a number of rectangles and while showing ask the user to scroll... right? Why it is not happening here?

Comment: @gpuguy, I don' understand your comment. please elaborate

Comment: Means you can easily view 1000 pages of word document by scrolling down, then why not these rectangles?

Comment: Because words don't have a regular pattern like squares.